# How to display each group of items on a new sheet in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a simple Spring-based web application for reporting about measurement tools. I'm using the following [JRXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports) pattern (generated by [TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio)), let's say `report_3.jrxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Default" isDefault="true" pdfFontName="ARIAL.TTF" pdfEncoding="Cp1251"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="polviz" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="polzex" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="polnaim" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tip" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="klt" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="pred" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="zavn" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="npasp" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="pp" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="n" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="84">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[УТВЕРЖДАЮ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="14" width="100" height="20"  />
                <text><![CDATA[Главный метролог]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="410" y="39" width="120" height="1"  />
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="39" width="140" height="30"  />
                <textElement>
                    <font size="6"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[(подпись, расшифровка подписи, дата)]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="85" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-2" y="0" width="559" height="20"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Общая ведомость средств измерений по цехам]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="83" width="554" height="1"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="66" width="554" height="16"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{polviz}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="52" width="552" height="14"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[/ N - не проверено, R - ремонт, К - консервация /]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="1" y="30" width="552" height="20"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{polzex}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="1" width="110" height="30"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Наим. средства изм.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="1" width="50" height="30"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Тип]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="160" y="1" width="68" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Предел изм.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="1" width="78" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Зав. ном.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="554" height="1"  />
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="109" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="159" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="228" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  />
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="359" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  />
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="360" y="1" width="74" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ном. пасп.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="434" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="436" y="0" width="54" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Периодич.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="490" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="490" y="0" width="62" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Неп,Рем,Конс]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="554" y="-1" width="1" height="33"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="230" y="1" width="46" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Кл.т.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="277" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="33">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="19" width="553" height="1" forecolor="#E5E5E5"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="2" y="1" width="108" height="18"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{polnaim}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="111" y="1" width="50" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tip}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="161" y="1" width="68" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pred}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="230" y="1" width="48" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{klt}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="278" y="1" width="82" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{zavn}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="1" width="76" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{npasp}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="436" y="1" width="56" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pp}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="492" y="1" width="62" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{n}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="21"/>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Part of `JasperReportsController` controller:

```
...
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/jasper-reports/")
public class JasperReportsController {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private MetrologServices metrologServices;

    @Autowired 
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "report_3")
    public ModelAndView generateThirdPdfReport(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        JasperReportsPdfView jrPdfView = new JasperReportsPdfView();
        List<ReportDTO> records = findInventoryReportData();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("records", records);

        jrPdfView.setUrl("classpath:report_3.jrxml");
        jrPdfView.setReportDataKey("records");
        jrPdfView.setApplicationContext(appContext);

        modelAndView = new ModelAndView(jrPdfView, map);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    private List<ReportDTO> findInventoryReportData() {
        List<ReportDTO> result = metrologServices.loadInventoryData();
        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

Somewhere in the view I call the controller:

`$("#btn-print").attr("href", "${home}/metrolog/jasper-reports/report_3");`

As a result I get the following report:

[image]

I want to start the list of measurement tools for each department with a new page. For example, part of the measuring tools belongs to department 1, another part belongs to department 2, etc.

Comment: Duplicates: [Jasper Reports subreport on a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13880978/876298)

Comment: You can also use pagebreak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise the following documentation: [Chapter 14. View technologies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html#view-jasper-reports), see section *"14.7.4. Working with Sub-Reports"*:

> JasperReports provides support for embedded sub-reports within your
>   master report files. There are a wide variety of mechanisms for
>   including sub-reports in your report files. The easiest way is to hard
>   code the report path and the SQL query for the sub report into your
>   design files. The drawback of this approach is obvious - the values
>   are hard-coded into your report files reducing reusability and making
>   it harder to modify and update report designs. To overcome this you
>   can configure sub-reports declaratively and you can include additional
>   data for these sub-reports directly from your controllers.
>
> To control which sub-report files are included in a master report
>   using Spring, your report file must be configured to accept
>   sub-reports from an external source. To do this you declare a
>   parameter in your report file like so:
>
> ```
> <parameter name="ProductsSubReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
> ```
>
> Then, you define your sub-report to use this sub-report parameter:
>
> ```
> <subreport>
>     <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="5" y="25" width="325"
>         height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#ffcc99"/>
>     <subreportParameter name="City">
>         <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
>     </subreportParameter>
>     <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{SubReportData}]]></dataSourceExpression>
>     <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport">
>                   <![CDATA[$P{ProductsSubReport}]]></subreportExpression>
> </subreport>
> ```
>
> This defines a master report file that expects the sub-report to be
>   passed in as an instance of
>   `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReports` under the parameter
>   `ProductsSubReport`. When configuring your Jasper view class, you can
>   instruct Spring to load a report file and pass into the JasperReports
>   engine as a sub-report using the `subReportUrls` property:
>
> ```
> <property name="subReportUrls">
>     <map>
>         <entry key="ProductsSubReport" value="/WEB-INF/reports/subReportChild.jrxml"/>
>     </map>
> </property>
> ```
>
> Here, the key of the `Map` corresponds to the name of the sub-report
>   parameter in th report design file, and the entry is the URL of the
>   report file. Spring will load this report file, compiling it if
>   necessary, and will pass into the JasperReports engine under the given
>   key.

Hence, the master report file can be represented as follows:

report_3.jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <style name="Default" isDefault="true" pdfFontName="ARIAL.TTF" pdfEncoding="Cp1251"/>

    <parameter name="Kpp9SubReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <parameter name="Kpp9SubReportData" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>

    <parameter name="..." class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <parameter name="..." class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>

    ...
    etc

    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="84">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[УТВЕРЖДАЮ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="14" width="100" height="20"  />
                <text><![CDATA[Главный метролог]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="410" y="39" width="120" height="1"  />
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="39" width="140" height="30"  />
                <textElement>
                    <font size="6"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[(подпись, расшифровка подписи, дата)]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
    <band height="500">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-10" y="0" width="325" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="false" backcolor="#ffcc99"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{DepartmentKpp9SubReportData}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport">
                                <![CDATA[$P{DepartmentKpp9SubReport}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <break type="Page">
            <reportElement x="-10" y="1" width="325" height="10" key="element-1"/>
        </break>
    </band>
    <band height="500">
        <subreport> 
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-10" y="2" width="325" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="false" backcolor="#ffcc99"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{Department8SubReportData}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport">
                                <![CDATA[$P{Department8SubReport}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <break type="Page">
            <reportElement x="-10" y="3" width="325" height="1" key="element-2"/>
        </break>
    </band>
    <band height="500">
       ...
    </band>
    ...
    etc
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="21"/>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The sub-report report_4.jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <style name="Default" isDefault="true" pdfFontName="ARIAL.TTF" pdfEncoding="Cp1251"/>
    <field name="polviz" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="polzex" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="polnaim" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tip" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="klt" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="pred" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="zavn" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="npasp" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="pp" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="n" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="85" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-2" y="0" width="559" height="20"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Общая ведомость средств измерений по цехам]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="83" width="554" height="1"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="66" width="554" height="16"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{polviz}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="52" width="552" height="14"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[/ N - не проверено, R - ремонт, К - консервация /]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="1" y="30" width="552" height="20"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{polzex}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="1" width="110" height="30"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Наим. средства изм.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="1" width="50" height="30"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Тип]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="160" y="1" width="68" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Предел изм.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="1" width="78" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Зав. ном.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="554" height="1"  />
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="109" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="159" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="228" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  />
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="359" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  />
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="360" y="1" width="74" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ном. пасп.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="434" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="436" y="0" width="54" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Периодич.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="490" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="490" y="0" width="62" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Неп,Рем,Конс]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="554" y="-1" width="1" height="33"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="230" y="1" width="46" height="30"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Кл.т.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="277" y="-2" width="1" height="34"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="33">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="19" width="553" height="1" forecolor="#E5E5E5"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="2" y="1" width="108" height="18"  />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{polnaim}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="111" y="1" width="50" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tip}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="161" y="1" width="68" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pred}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="230" y="1" width="48" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{klt}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="278" y="1" width="82" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{zavn}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="360" y="1" width="76" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{npasp}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="436" y="1" width="56" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pp}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="492" y="1" width="62" height="18"  >
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{n}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="21"/>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Part of `JasperReportsController` controller(we consider only the case of one department, the other sub-reports can be obtained similarly using the same templates report_3.jrxml and report_4.jrxml):

```
...
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/jasper-reports/")
public class JasperReportsController {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private MetrologServices metrologServices;

    @Autowired 
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="report_3")
    public ModelAndView generateThirdPdfReport(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        JasperReportsPdfView jrPdfView = new JasperReportsPdfView();
        List<ReportDTO> records = findInventoryReportData();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("records", records);

        Properties subReports = new Properties();
        subReports.put("Kpp9SubReport", "classpath:report_4.jrxml");
        List<ReportDTO> kpp9SubReportRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        records.forEach(record -> {
            if(record.getPolzex().equalsIgnoreCase("КПП 9")) {
                kpp9SubReportRecords.add(record);
            }
        });

        JRDataSource kpp9SubReportDataSource = 
            new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(kpp9SubReportRecords);
        parameterMap.put("Kpp9SubReportData", kpp9SubReportDataSource);

        jrPdfView.setSubReportUrls(subReports);
        jrPdfView.setSubReportDataKeys("Kpp9SubReportData");

        jrPdfView.setUrl("classpath:report_3.jrxml");
        jrPdfView.setReportDataKey("records");
        jrPdfView.setApplicationContext(appContext);

        modelAndView = new ModelAndView(jrPdfView, map);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    private List<ReportDTO> findInventoryReportData() {
        List<ReportDTO> result = metrologServices.loadInventoryData();
        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

As a result, we getting such a report, as required(in the department there are only five measuring instruments):

[image]